# Probability of winning

Tags: probability

If the probability of you winning a game is 1/2, a set has 5 games,  and if 1 game wins you the set, what is the probability of you winning 10 sets on the trot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of winning one game during a given set (and hence winning the set) is $1 - (1/2)^5$. The probability of winning ten sets in a row is therefore $(1-(1/2)^5)^{10} = 0.727...$.

**NB** I assume the outcome of all games are independent.

Comment: Just working out my strategy for Roulette when I go next time :-). Thanks.

Comment: No problem, though I'm sure when you're playing Roulette your chances of winning a lot of money won't be $72\%$! $\ $;)

Comment: true that ... :-)